# Unable to run GCP VM Instance with a container

Tags: docker, virtual-machines, containers, gcp

On GCP you can create VM instances and configure it to pull a docker image to run a container. The container doesn't seem to be running in my case. When I SSH into the VM and run `docker images` no images are listed implying the instance has not pulled the image. No errors logged.

The service account used to create the instance has the `storage.ObjectViewer` IAM Permission. Does the service account need additional permissions to pull and run a container? What can I check to figure out the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a debian12, setup docker ang just go.

If you use COOS (Chromium OS), you have to run you're docker by hand.

If you want to pull directly, you can try with "debian" from a fresh CoOS. I nerver failed. Can you join screenshots ?

Answer (score 0):

A firewall rule was preventing the VM from accessing the container image. After fixing the issue, the image was downloaded and the container started.